Pointwise, uniform and total convergence of a real parametric function series.
Exercise
Consider the function series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{n^\alpha x}{n^{\alpha+1}x^2+1}.
$$

Find $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ such that the series converges pointwise in $[0,+\infty[$.
Find $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ such that the series converges totally in $[0,+\infty[$.
Are there any $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ such that the series converges uniformly but not totaly on $[0,+\infty[$?

Solution

The series converges pointwise in $[0,+\infty[$ for every $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$.

The series converges totally in $[0,+\infty[$ for $\alpha<-1$. This is because we have that


$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sup_{x\in[0,+\infty[}\bigg|(-1)^n\frac{n^\alpha x}{n^{\alpha+1}x^2+1}\bigg|=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n^{\frac{\alpha-1}{2}}}{2},
$$
which converges if and only if $\alpha<-1$.

I am struggling with this request. Such $\alpha$s, given point 2., must be greater or equal $-1$, but this is all I managed to find.

Can anybody help me with point 3?

"Converges totally" - do you mean absolutely?

I mean that the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty||f_n(x)||_\infty$$ is convergent

This is called absolute convergence (with arbitrary norm, not necessary $L_\infty$).

@mihaild as far as I know, total convergence is different from absolute convergence

AFAIK absolute convergence is defined for normed spaces, and measn convergence of norms. But probably it's good idea to have separate notion to not confuse functional series with parametrized numeric. In 3 - you mean uniform convergence as numeric series, right?
